# NSPredicate unable to parse the format string

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have a problem with NSPredicate parsing

```
NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
[array addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE = 1"]]
```

Error is `Unable to parse the format string "NONE = 1"`

Comment: What are you trying to make your predicate to do? If you explain what you are trying to do instead of _only_ showing us the code we can not only point out errors in the code but actually help you come up with a solution for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

`NONE` is a keyword in predicates meaning "none of these should be true". You can think of it like this: `NONE(=1)` where `=1` is not a valid expression. That is why it's unable to parse.

You would use the `NONE` keyword to say that none of the values in some collection property should evaluate to true. For example: `NONE someArrayProperty = 1` would look through all the values of someArrayProperty and check if any of them is equal to 1.

---

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html):

> **`NONE`**
>   Specifies none of the elements in the following expression. For example, `NONE children.age < 18`. This is logically equivalent to `NOT (ANY ...)`.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem you should "mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer." as described in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)